# Create array containing the single chars of a string. How does these regular expression work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I guess I start with some example code:

```
var sentence = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.';

// Makes an array with the single chars of the sentence as elements.
sentence = sentence.split(''); 

// Makes a multi-dimensional array. 
var result = sentence.map(function(ch) {
  // Using /./ leads to an multi-dimensional array too.
  //  Each array contains two empty strings as elements.
  //  => ["", ""]
  return ch.split(/. /); 
});

result.forEach(function(item, i) {
  console.log(item);  // [ ["L"], ["o"], ["r"] ... ] 
});
```

The purpose is clear to me: It's for making a multi-dimensional array. Each element got one char of the sentence.

What I don't understand is the regular expression which is used.

. stands for one arbitrary character in regular expressions.

**What's the purpose of the blank after the dot ( . ) ?**

Moreover:
If I get rid of the blank and write just /./ then the results are arrays too. Each array contains two empty strings ( "" ) .

That behaviour isn't clear to me too.

**Can anyone explain the described regular expression behaviour?**

Like to add:
I have seen the code-snippet here ... https://davidwalsh.name/write-javascript-promises

At the bottom of the section "Chaining".

Comment: It doesn't really do *anything*. That line would be more easily written as `return [ch];`. The pattern could never match a single character.

Comment: If you start playing with the first split - `sentence = sentence.split('');` - then you'll see some *action*. Try `result = sentence.split(/[ ,.]+/);`, skip the `map` part and you'll get an array of the individual words, since `[ ,.]+` matches any sequence of space, dot and comma (the're removed and the rest put into an array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"x".split(/. /)
```

has the same effect as

```
"x".split(/rabbit/)
```

It just collect a part of the string that doesn't contain the delimiter (=the whole string), and then stops.

```
"x".split(/./)
```

collects a part that doesn't match `.` (=an empty string), then consumes the delimiter (=`x`) and then appends the rest of the string (which is empty) to the result.

Comment: Okay. If I get that right: The split() method ALWAYS returns at least one element. If the regular expression doesn't match anything then it is the string to split itself?

Comment: Yes, with one exception: if _both_ the subject and the separator are empty, it returns an empty array: `''.split('')`.